# Xcode build of flutter app times out during build

Tags: ios, macos, flutter, dart

I am trying to emulate our flutter app on Mac and I Get this error:

> ProcessException: Process timed out:

Command:

```
/usr/bin/env xcrun xcodebuild -configuration Debug -quiet -workspace Runner.xcworkspace -scheme Runner BUILD_DIR=/Users/samcromer/Desktop/LightBridge-2/build/ios -sdk iphonesimulator -arch x86_64 FLUTTER_SUPPRESS_ANALYTICS=true COMPILER_INDEX_STORE_ENABLE=NO -showBuildSettings
```

Is there a way to fix this? I am a windows dev so this doesn't make a lot of sense to me.